Django translation html not translating the string when html files are included using include statement
Django html template not translating the strings when html files are included using include statement
views.py:
  def process_request(request, data)
    context = {
        'category': datacategory,
        'info': data.abc
        'language_code': language_code
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template='.../components/test.html', context=context)

test.html:
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<div class="">
    <p>{% translate 'hello world' %}</p>
    {% include 'hash_processor/components/test2.html' %}
</div>

test2.html:
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<div class="">
    <p>{% translate 'hi... world234567' %}</p>
        {% include 'hash_processor/components/test3.html' %}
</div>

test3.html:
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<div class="">
    <p>{% translate 'heyy world234567' %}</p>
</div>

django.po:
#: templates/hash_processor/components/test.html:6
msgid "hello world"
msgstr "hgfghjkl wojehfvejh"

#: templates/hash_processor/components/test2.html:6
msgid "hi... world234567"
msgstr "hi....fjkherjfger kfhgerhjkf233"

#: templates/hash_processor/components/test3.html:6
msgid "heyy world234567"
msgstr "heyyy...ghewjfgdjhdfr kfhgerhjkf233"

output on broswer:

String coming for translation in django.po but not rendering in browser,
till level 2 it is working fine, but at 3rd level translated string not showing
how can we achieve translation for such translations files?
